# Adding custom field from Easy Property Listing Wordpress plugin

Tags: php, html, wordpress, content-management-system

I'm using the Easy Property Listings Wordpress plugin (http://easypropertylistings.com.au/) and I'm setting up some custom fields. I have managed to get it working in the CMS so that the field shows and you can input data by using the following:

```
function listings_callback($meta_fields) {
$custom_field = array(
        'id'        =>   'epl-property-listing-custom-data-id',
        'label'     =>   __('Listing Details', 'epl'),
        'post_type' =>   array('property'),
        'context'   =>   'normal',
        'priority'  =>   'default',
        'groups'    =>   array(
            array(
                'id'        =>   'property_listing_lot_width',
                'columns'   =>   '1',
                'label'     =>   'Lot Width',
                'fields'    =>   array(
                    array(
                        'name'      =>   'property_listing_lot_width',
                        'label'     =>   __('Lot Width', 'epl'),
                        'type'      =>   'text',
                        'maxlength' =>   '150'
                    )
                )
            )
        )
    );
$meta_fields[] = $custom_field;
return $meta_fields;
}
add_filter( 'epl_listing_meta_boxes' , 'listings_callback' );
```

Now I'm trying to add the custom field on the front end in my template but I have no idea how to call it.

Any help would be appreciated as I've looked through all their documentation and can't seem to find anything that would help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out how to go about it and thought I would share the answer in case anyone else is having the same issue.

After the code above I required the following:

```
function my_custom_text_field_callback() {
global $property;

$custom_text_field = $property->get_property_meta('property_listing_lot_width');
if ( isset($custom_text_field) ) {
    echo $custom_text_field;
}
}
// Add after the_content of the listing
add_action( 'epl_property_content_after' , 'my_custom_text_field_callback' );
```

The code depends on which type of field you are pulling. There are instructions here on if you are using different fields such as 'numbers' or 'select boxes'.

http://easypropertylistings.com.au/docs/epl_listing_meta_boxes-filter-all-available-meta-fields/

Then once this is setup in functions.php you will need to add the following to your template file to call the field:

```
<?php do_action('epl_property_content_after'); ?>
```

I think is is where I got confused as I was trying to call 'my_custom_text_field_callback' instead of 'epl_property_content_after.

Also don't forget to check that you have text actually written in the CMS. I found that if I made changes to naming fields my content would disappear.